# How can I create_or_update in seeds.rb for translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize3

I now have the following in my seeds.rb

```
os = OrderStatus.find(1)
os.translations.create(:status => "In aanmaak", :locale => "nl")
os.translations.create(:status => "Creating", :locale => "en")
```

However this creates doubles.  So I tried to do a create_or_update instead of create but that doesn't seem to be supported.  I am using globalize3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment you could do the following:

```
os = OrderStatus.find(1)
os.translations.where(locale: "nl").first_or_create.update_attributes(status: "In aanmaak")
os.translations.where(locale: "en").first_or_create.update_attributes(status: "Creating")
```

I'm not sure if there's a nicer way of writing this, but you could create your own method:

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def first_or_update(locale, status)
    where(locale: locale).first_or_create.update_attributes(status: status)
  end
end

os.translations.first_or_update("en", "Creating")
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that if I change the status to for example:
os.translations.where(:status => "Creation", :locale => "en").first_or_create
I will have 2 english translations for that OrderStatus

Comment: Would you always change both fields or would one remain the same?

Comment: For every OrderStatus there can exist only 1 translation in 1 language, so 1 for en 1 for nl ...  So it should search for locale and  insert or update text.  So one will remain the same (the locale).

Comment: Great, this works, I just use:
os.translations.where(:locale => "nl").first_or_create.update_attributes(:status => "In aanmaak")